# EF Core defaultValueSql how to set value from SELECT

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have DB migration where `FormTemplateId` - foreign key and I need to set default value as `Id` of the latest record in `[dbo].[FormTemplates]`:

```
  migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
                name: "FormTemplateId",
                table: "ContainerMasterTypes",
                type: "int",
                nullable: false,
                defaultValueSql: "SELECT TOP 1 [Id] FROM [dbo].[FormTemplates] ORDER BY [Id] DESC");
```

and have error:
`Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.'`

What's wrong? How can I fix that error?

Comment: What database are you using? Are you sure it allows specifying select statements as default constraint?

Comment: @GuruStron MS SQL

Comment: Have you checked if it allows to specify such constraint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity Framework only allows you to do what you can do already in SQL Server. For example, with the following table setup:

```sql
create table dbo.FormTemplates (
  Id int not null identity(1,1),
  Name nvarchar(50) not null
);
insert dbo.FormTemplates (Name) values (N'Foo'), (N'Bar'), (N'Baz');

create table dbo.ContainerMasterTypes (
  Id int not null identity(1,1),
  Name nvarchar(50) not null
);
```

Attempting to modify the `ContainerMasterTypes` table to add the new column with a subquery in the default constraint as you are doing would fail...

```sql
alter table dbo.ContainerMasterTypes
  add FormTemplateId int not null
    constraint DF_ContainerMasterTypes_FormTemplateId
      default (SELECT TOP 1 [Id] FROM [dbo].[FormTemplates] ORDER BY [Id] DESC);
```

... with the error message that you are seeing in .NET:

> Msg 1046 Level 15 State 1 Line 3
>
> Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.

To do this in SQL Server you would instead wrap the query in a Scalar User-Defined Function and reference that from the default constraint, i.e.:

```sql
create function dbo.LatestFormTemplateId()
returns int as
begin
  return (SELECT TOP 1 [Id] FROM [dbo].[FormTemplates] ORDER BY [Id] DESC)
end
go
alter table dbo.ContainerMasterTypes
  add FormTemplateId int not null
    constraint DF_ContainerMasterTypes_FormTemplateId
      default (dbo.LatestFormTemplateId());
```

Testing that with data...

```sql
insert dbo.ContainerMasterTypes (Name, FormTemplateId) values (N'Something', 1);
insert dbo.ContainerMasterTypes (Name) values (N'Else');

select * from dbo.FormTemplates;
select * from dbo.ContainerMasterTypes;
```

Would yield the results:

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Foo |
| 2 | Bar |
| 3 | Baz |

| Id | Name | FormTemplateId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Something | 1 |
| 2 | Else | 3 |

You need to do the same thing from Entity Framework as well, creating a Scalar UDF that wraps your query and then adding your new column with the default constraint referencing the UDF.